# How to valid sharedpreference value in android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am checking all these at `splashscreen` activity,

So I am giving this,

```
SharedPreferences spf = getSharedPreferences("myprfs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor spe = spf.edit();
String name = spf.getString("name","");
String id = spf.getString("id","");
String class = spf.getString("class","");
String roll = spf.getString("roll","");
spe.commit();

 if((spe != null) && (name != null) && (id != null) && (class != null) && (roll != null)){
     Intent i = new Intent(Startpage.this,Welcome.class);
     startActivity(i);
     Startpage.this.finish();

 }
 else{
     Intent i = new Intent(Startpage.this,MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(i);
     Startpage.this.finish();
 }
```

when I open app startup page directly moves to welcome page,

but I want to move `splashscreen` page to `MainActivity` when there is no values saved in shared-preferences

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068855/get-sharedpreferences-value-from-another-activity) to get shared-preference values

can any one suggest me how to give condition in this kind

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Condition is not working in sharedpreferences android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46661277/condition-is-not-working-in-sharedpreferences-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String name = spf.getString("name","");
```

This method creates a shared pref if it doesn't exist already with the default value as the second argument. So in your case, shared pref are saved with empty string as value when user visited the app for first time.

Just change your default value to null since your checks are on null value and it will work  -

```
String name = spf.getString("name",null);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
spf.getString("name","");
```

return as default value a empty string.

Idea:

why not use

```
spf.contains("name")
```

that return true or false?
Alternatively you can check if string is empty or null with TextUtils.isEmpty()
method.

Answer (score 0):

you are putting `null check` on the string but while reading from the shared preferences you are setting them to `empty string` if the value is not found in the shared prefs. change your checks to `String.isEmpty()` in your if condition.

Answer (score 0):

because `null` and `""`are different，

You should use `android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty(CharSequence str)`instead of `str != null`

Another way is :
`String name = spf.getString("name",null);` ,and then like `if (Str != null)`

For me,i always usee the first way i said to determine whether String is empty.

Hope it helps you :)