# How to get Sharedprfs String value to spinner..? ANDROID

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, spinner

I have given [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45834331/8039571) to save data with sharedpreference

so I want to get value to a spinner, here I have given this

```
SharedPreferences spf = getSharedPreferences("myprfs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String ret = spf.getString("ctyp","");
```

Here  am getting the value to a String, I want to assign a same value to a spinner.

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)                                       
    if(ret.equals(spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString())){  
    spinner.setSelection(i);                                  
     break;                                                
    }
```

I am getting this error

```
'java.lang.Object android.widget.Spinner.getItemAtPosition(int)' on a null object reference
```

Can any one suggest me correct ans..

Comment: check you have bind the spinner ???

Answer (score 0):

Your `spinner` should be null. Set a breakpoint to confirm that. Remember to run in **debug** mode to make the breakpoint to "break"

Most probably:

1. not done a `findViewById`
2. using ButterKnife and forgot to bind it

If you've done the above, but spinner is still null, in which lifecycle method are you running above code? Maybe you're trying to touch the UI *before* it's loaded